# MapReduce - use hadoop configuration object to read in a text file

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I am a homework assignment that requires me to run the k-means algorithm with hadoop/mapreduce/java. Each iteration of the k-means algorithm is one MapReduce job, and the question involves chaining n jobs, where n is the number of iterations of the k-means algorithm we choose to run.

We are given a file of initial centroids, called centroids.txt, shown below:

```
1. 0 0.64 0.64 0 0.32
2. 0.21 0.28 0.5 0 0.14
3. 0.06 0 0.71 0 1.23 
4. 1.03 1.36 0.32 0.51 0
5. 0 0 0 0 0.63
```

...the row numbers are not in the file. each row is a 5-dimensional vector, and represents an initial cluster centroid for the k-means algorithm. here we have 5 initial clusters.

Next we have a file of datapoints that we must assign to the clusters, called data.txt, shown below:

```
1. 0 0.64 0.64 0 0.32
2. 0.21 0.28 0.5 0 0.14
3. 0.06 0 0.71 0 1.23
4. 0 0 0 0 0.63 
5. 0 0 0 0 0.63 
6. ... 
...
```

the ... here indicates that we many rows of datapoints (~10000 for this problem). Again each row is a 5-dimensional vector.

Okay, now for my question, which relates to structuring the MapReduce job, which is something I am not too familiar with currently (mapreduce that is). For each map function, the input file is the data.txt file. This is the file that we need to read, check each line, check what centroid the line belongs in, and create an appropriate key-value pair. However, HOW do I read in the centroids.txt file to the mapper? My professor gave the following hint:

"You will also need to share the location of the centroid file with the mapper. There are many ways to do this and you can use any method you find suitable.  One way is to use the Hadoop Configuration object. You can set it as a property in the Configuration object and retrieve the property value in the Mapper setup function."

For this I am confused. My program has a main function, a run function, a mapper and a reducer. It was also suggested that I use the Configuration set() and get() methods - then I can set the filename for each iteration in the configuration and then pass that to the job. Then in the mapper you can read from that filename.

This is all a bit confusing. Do I create the hadoop configuration object in the main() or run() functions? I set() in my main function and then call get() in my map function, or do i set() in my run function? It further complicates things that I have to run my map and reduce functions n times in a for loop, each time using a new/updated centroids.txt file.

Any thoughts appreciated on this!

Answer (score 0):

It's actually very simple. Hadoop mapper has `#setup` method that is called at the beginning to configure a mapper. What you have to do is to read centroids.txt file in this method:

```
class MyMapper extends Mapper {

    double[][] centroids = new double[5][];

    public void setup(Configuration conf) {
         InputStream is = FileSystem.get(conf).open(new Path("centroids.txt"));
         // read centroid values
    }
}
```

If you don't want to hardcode file path in mapper code, you can pass it to configuration object before submitting the job:

```
conf.set("centroids.path", "centroids.txt");
```

and then read it in mapper

```
InputStream is = FileSystem.get(conf).open(new Path(conf.get("centroids.path")));
```